# Using model attributes for the page style on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I want to change the aspect of some html elements representing table rows from a model. In particular, my `Component` model has a `:rating` column:

```
create_table "components", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "description"
  t.string   "repository_url"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "rating", default: 5 # color in the view to be defined by this value
end
```

And, in the view, the existing components (`Component.all`) are rendered as links:

```
- @components.each do |components|
 = link_to component.name, component, class: "rating_#{component.rating}"
```

As you can imagine, the way I am handling this by defines the style for `rating_1`...`rating_10` in the corresponding css file:

```
.componenttag.rating_1 {
    background-color : black
}

...

.componenttag.rating_10 {
    background-color : green
}
```

This works as a simple solution, but **I have the impression that there is a better (and more elegant) way of solving this problem or other similar ones**. Am I wrong? :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems quite elegant to me. I wouldn't do it any other way.

Comment: Thanks @RubyRacer . The truth is I have little experience with Rails and webapps in general, and repeating the `.rating_N` part in the CSS looked to me as a newbie thing :D